# Using CubeRefractionMapping with THREE.CubeCamera renders upside down

Tags: three.js

If I set the renderTarget mapping for my cube camera to THREE.CubeRefractionMapping, it renders upside down.

```
_myCubeCamera.renderTarget.mapping = THREE.CubeRefractionMapping;
```

It seems related to the issue discussed in [this post](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/3702#issuecomment-21755605) where the default orientation of the CubeCamera's component cameras are upside down. I tried tinkering around with these orientations in the THREE.js source code but only made things worse.

So, is there a correct way to use CubeRefractionMapping with CubeCamera? or a workaround?

r73

Comment: You would provide a valuable service if you would continue tracking down the issue and fix it. : - )

Comment: Found a workaround, see below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround: When assigning the envMap to the material, use THREE.BackSide.

```
var sphereMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( 
    { 
        envMap: myCubeCamera.renderTarget, 
        side: THREE.BackSide, 
        refractionRatio: .09 
     } );
```

A complete example is [here](http://rwoodley.org/MyContent/WIP/59-RefractionStudy/main.html).

Not sure why this works, but it does, and that's what the original poster (me!) wanted.

Comment: (1) Why are you using a cube camera in your example? Why not use `4.jpg` as your `envMap` with mapping `THREE.EquirectangularRefractionMapping`? (2) `_mirrorSphereCamera.position = _mirrorSphere.position;` is illegal in three.js. The `position` property is immutable. Use `copy()` instead.

Comment: re (1). I have a more complicated scene in mind, this was just a simple example. re (2). Thanks, noted.